# How to load static html site locally on Chrome OS/Chromebook?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have a few HTML/CSS files that I'd like to load, modify, and test in the Chrome browser on Chrome OS running on a Chromebook.

Is there a way to load a static website locally given this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you host your files on google drive, not only is it free but you are able to modify the files directly with chrome OS. to access the files in code, use http://googledrive.com/host/IDNumberOfFile OR
http://googledrive.com/host/IDNumberOfFolder/filename.blah OR if you use gweb.io
http://NameOfWebsite.gweb.io/fileName.blah